# React Hook Form Register Two Range Inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm in the process of putting together a reusable range slider component with two knobs on the slider. Its a slightly modified version of https://codesandbox.io/s/b9l0g?file=/src/multiRangeSlider/MultiRangeSlider.tsx:95-131. To accomplish this i'm using two input fields. Is there a way to register both input fields so they return in an array when the form data is submitted? Something like [24, 100]

**View**

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm()

const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log(data)
}

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <RangeSlider
            name="rangeslider"
            register={register}
            errors={errors}
            isRequired={true}
            min={0}
            max={1000}
        />
    </form>
)
```

**RangeSlider**

```
    <input
        type="range"
        {...register(name, {
            required: {
                value: isRequired,
                message: `${name} is required`,
            },
        })}
        min={min}
        max={max}
        value={minVal}
        ref={minValRef}
        onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            const value = Math.min(+event.target.value, maxVal - 1)
            setMinVal(value)
            event.target.value = value.toString()
        }}
        className={`thumb thumb--zindex-3 ${
            minVal > max - 100 ? 'thumb--zindex-5' : ''
        }`}
    />
    <input
        type="range"
        {...register(name, {
            required: {
                value: isRequired,
                message: `${name} is required`,
            },
        })}
        min={min}
        max={max}
        value={maxVal}
        ref={maxValRef}
        onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            const value = Math.max(+event.target.value, minVal + 1)
            setMaxVal(value)
            event.target.value = value.toString()
        }}
        className="thumb thumb--zindex-4"
    />

    <div className="slider">
        <div className="slider__track"></div>
        <div ref={range} className="slider__range"></div>
        <div className="slider__left-value">{minVal}</div>
        <div className="slider__right-value">{maxVal}</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/getvalues) help?
You are giving both inputs the same name which I assume will be a problem in order to get their values.

Then, on onSubmit you could do something like:
```
return [getValues('lowerRange'), getValues('upperRange')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot register two inputs with the same name and retrieve values for both. However, you can alter their names. For example:

```
{...register(`${name}.lower`)}
```

and

```
{...register(`${name}.upper`)}
```

Let's say `name = "age"`, then your `data` object will look like this:

```
{
    age: {
         lower: 12,
         upper: 18
    }        
}
```

However, it might be easier in the first place to use a [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller). I have edited the code sandbox you used as a template to show how a Controller can be used here.
Look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-range-slider-react-ts-forked-wwtgk?file=/src/Form.tsx).